# Parse "struct" xml in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-rpc

I am facing a parsing problem with xml generated in C. I need to parse Xml like below to Java objects. Is there any elegant way how to deal with this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
          <member>
            <name>resps</name>
            <value>
              <array>
                <data> 
                  <member>
                    <name>id</name>
                    <value>
                      <int>10</int>
                    </value>
                  </member> 
                  <member>
                    <name>name</name>
                    <value>
                      <string>Test Name</string>
                    </value>
                  </member>
                </data>
              </array>
            </value>
          </member> 
        </struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

Comment: [Use an XML parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jaxb](https://jaxb.java.net/) api.
All you need is a [xsd](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/) document for your xml. Then jaxb will generate the Java classes that you can use in your program.

Comment: Thx. I will have a look. The problem is that I don't have the xsd only plain xml.